# In Kali Linux, how can I open files in a safe manner without disconnecting internet?

Tags: linux, sandbox

I downloaded a few documents over Tor as of late. I am mindful of the issues which I can confront when I open a document downloaded through Tor in an online machine.

I want to know how to open these documents in a sandboxed environment on a machine connected to the internet as I have to research a few points on the web while going through the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual machine which hasn't any interface connected to the internet. Use Host-only or NAT to isolate the machine.

Comment: And do an snapshot first. Then you can get back to the initial state free of possible malware. Anyway he is asking to have the machine connected to the internet, not to be isolated on networking.

Comment: I mean the vm must be isolated from internet. Some files (such as PDF) can, once opened, make http requests. On the other hand, if its vm is isolated, requests could be done but they won't get any response.

Comment: @NokosiPow What are my options if I don't want to use a VM?

Comment: Have another PC which isn't and will never be connected to the internet.